# R efficient way to convert named/nested list to data frame

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I'm trying to convert a named and nested list into a data frame (FYI, the list is a product of `st_nn` function, where nn stands for nearest neighbor and d stands for distance). Below is a reproducible example.

```
nn <- list(c(1,2), c(2,3))
d <- list(c(0, 100), c(11,43))
l <- list(nn, d)
```

`df` is what I want.

```
df <- data.frame(nn1 = c(1,2),
                nn2 = c(2,3),
                d1 = c(0, 11),
                d2 = c(100, 43))
```

The code below does the job in a somewhat ad-hoc fashion, but I'm curious if there's a more elegant approach (preferably `tidyverse` approach).

```
df2 <- data.frame(rbindlist(l) %>% t()) %>% rename(nn1 = X1, nn2 = X2, d1 = X3, d2 = X4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the `list`, `rbind` the inner list elements and `cbind` the outer `list`

```
out <-  do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(l, function(x) do.call(rbind, x)))
names(out) <- c('nn1', 'nn2', 'd1', 'd2')
out
#  nn1 nn2 d1  d2
#1   1   2  0 100
#2   2   3 11  43
```

---

Or with `map` and `unnest_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
map_dfc(l, ~ transpose(.x) %>%
                 map_dfc(~ tibble(col1 = .x) %>%
                           unnest(c(col1)))) %>%
       set_names(c('nn1', 'nn2', 'd1', 'd2'))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#    nn1   nn2    d1    d2
#* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     0   100
#2     2     3    11    43
```

Comment: looks like op wants column `d1` as `c(0, 11)` and column `d2` as `c(11, 43)`

Comment: @akrun Thanks for your answer! I've double-checked my question, and to me it seems like that ```d1``` has ```c(0,11)``` and ```d2``` has ```c(100,43)```. Correct me if my post is contradicting.

Comment: @qnp1521 have you checked my second answer..  I kept the first answer because I thought it could be a typo

Comment: @akrun Thanks! Yes the second one works well. Also, the first one works beautifully with one fix (```rbind``` instead of ```cbind``` inside ```lapply```). And I like the first approach better since it automatically creates more useful column names.